# How to import preferences(.epf) on eclipse startup which should be reflected with restart?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on `eclipse plugin`, which will import `preferences(.epf)` while startup.

I am using below code :

```java
@Override
    public void earlyStartup() 
    {       
        Display.getDefault().syncExec( new Runnable() {            


            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                     InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/pref.epf"));
                       Platform.getPreferencesService ().importPreferences (in);
}
catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            } 
        });
}
```

But I am getting below error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Preference node
>   "org.eclipse.core.net" has been removed.  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.checkRemoved(EclipsePreferences.java:200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:653)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.getBoolean(PreferenceManager.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.preferenceChange(ProxyManager.java:416)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences$3.run(EclipsePreferences.java:896)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.firePreferenceEvent(EclipsePreferences.java:899)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.remove(EclipsePreferences.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService$1.visit(PreferencesService.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.accept(EclipsePreferences.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyPreferences(PreferencesService.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.importPreferences(PreferencesService.java:685)
>     at
>   com.gemalto.shd.eclipsebundle.StartupClass$1.run(StartupClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 4 2 2014-04-11 18:00:50.950
>   !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences". !STACK 0
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Preference node
>   "org.eclipse.core.net" has been removed.  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.checkRemoved(EclipsePreferences.java:200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:653)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.getBoolean(PreferenceManager.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.preferenceChange(ProxyManager.java:416)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences$3.run(EclipsePreferences.java:896)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.firePreferenceEvent(EclipsePreferences.java:899)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.remove(EclipsePreferences.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.removeNode(EclipsePreferences.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService$1.visit(PreferencesService.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.accept(EclipsePreferences.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyPreferences(PreferencesService.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.importPreferences(PreferencesService.java:685)
>     at
>   com.gemalto.shd.eclipsebundle.StartupClass$1.run(StartupClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the import preferences dialog I think you need to specify a preference filter in the import:

```java
 IPreferenceFilter [] filters = new IPreferenceFilter[1];

 filters[0] = new IPreferenceFilter() {
     public String[] getScopes() {
       return new String[] {InstanceScope.SCOPE, ConfigurationScope.SCOPE};
     }

     public Map getMapping(String scope) {
       return null;
     }
 };

 IPreferencesService service = Platform.getPreferencesService();

 IExportedPreferences prefs = service.readPreferences(input stream);

 service.applyPreferences(prefs, filters);
```

(adapted from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1`)

Comment: That's really amazing Greg. Many Thanks for your help. I am new to Eclipse plugin development and was struggling since long. You are my savior. Thank you again.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. Is there any way to find which API is being called for a particular action performed on Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I usually use Eclipse Plugin Spy to find the code which is displaying the dialog (or view or whatever) and then read the source to see what it does - see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)